# Running .cmd file by C#

Tags: c#

I am using the mentioned code to run a cmd file. It is working properly in my local machine. However when I am running in a remote machine windows security warning is coming. How can i bypass that security warning. Any help?

```
string[] newFilePath = Directory.GetFiles(workingDir, "*.cmd");
foreach (var n in newFilePath) {
    finishedOld = false;
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format("\"" + n + "\"");
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Dispose();
    finishedOld = true;
}
```

[image: image of security warning]

Comment: One option is to [add that path as a trusted location](https://www.technipages.com/fix-we-cant-verify-who-created-this-file-error?share=email)

Comment: @Needy.Coder if you right click the CMD file on the remote machine and get properties, do you see a tickbox "This file came from another computer/unblock" ? You may be able to unblock it that way (and this only needs to be done once)